# Opening Files for Reading too Large for Memory

Tags: perl, memory-management

I have a simple Perl script that reads files of an expected format, saves some pertinent information to a hash, does some operation with the hash, and then closes the file and moves onto the next file.

I need to consider a scenario where my system memory is less than the size of the file arguments, so I thought, why not try it? So I limited my VirtualBox to 1GB of RAM, created a list of 1.5GB, and gave it to it as input. No errors are thrown, it just runs and runs.

I took a look at the system memory in use with the "free" command and it shows near 99% of the memory being used and not increasing at all over time. I have some interrupt handling code in my Perl script and when I press that, my vbox becomes unresponsive and I have to restart it.

**What I need to do** is input several mail lists formatted like

```
1-bob@bob.com
```

and send emails to each email address in the mail list. I keep track of all the email addresses by adding them to a hash. As each address is processed (i.e. added to the hash) I also validate it and send an email to it if it's good.

Is there a better way to test this? Am I doing something wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %email_db;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id, $email) = split /-/;
  push @{ $email_db{$id} }, $email;
}
```

The expected number of input files can range from one to five (I'm assuming here - the problem isn't specific) and the example given in terms of file sizes was 100MB system memory and 10GB file sizes. The number of entries in the hash at the end is unknown.

Each element of the hash has

```
key   = unique ID
value = array of email addresses for that ID
```

Comment: If you can, split up your input file into smaller pieces, doing analysis on those pieces that will fit within system memory. Write (serialize) the results to disk. Collate those results at the end. Regardless of your programming environment, think about a MapReduce-like procedure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you should iterate over the *contents* of `@ARGV` unless you need the index for another reason, so `for my $file (@ARGV) { .. }`. Use `split /-/` instead of `split("\055")` (octal 55 is the code point for ASCII hyphen). And use lexical file handles like `open my $list_fh, '<', $file`

Comment: The answer lies in what used to be commented `#..do more stuff w/the info`. As it stands now you are reading *all* of the data from your files into the hash `%email_db`. Unless your algorithm allows the data to be processed incrementally there is no way to do what you ask, but we cannot help you unless you explain what it is you need to do

Comment: @Borodin I added a "GOAL" section to the problem to show you what needs to be done. The algorithm isn't special at all. I just parse the file line by line, each line has an email in it, I get the email addy and I do stuff with the email addy(refer to edit).

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter: Okay, but you don't explain why you're keeping the hash in the first place. Unless there is a lot of duplicate date in the files your hash will grow to roughly the size of all the files on the command line. From your description, all you need to do is to send an email to every valid email that you encounter in the files, so your 50GB hash is unnecessary. Is there any more to it than that?

Comment: @Borodin At any time during the running of the script and at the end of the script, I must return a list of all the unique IDs ordered by number of email addresses. Keeping it has a hash with the ID as the key and an array of emails as the value makes this really easy to do. Sorry that I did not explain this.

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter:  Then you cannot do this with an in-memory hash. I recommend you use an `SQLite` database

Comment: @Borodin Unfortunately I am not allowed to do that. I modified the updated code as per your recommendation but am getting compilation errors. See any obvious errors? If not, no worries, I'll figure it out as this is off topic.

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter: I've fixed your code assuming that you just need to read through all the files on the command line, in wehich case you don't need to open them explicitly. You have to store the list of processed email addresses on disk somehow if it won't fit in memory: the people who say you're *"not allowed to do that"* have to permit a workable approach

Comment: Ah yes. There it is - expanding a file, adding a bit of overhead to make it a hash, and then ... holding it all in memory. You need a different way of doing what you're trying to do - a DB will do the trick. A flat 'journal' file might also do the trick - that'll be the same size as well though.

Comment: @Borodin if I wanted to use sqlite for this, what would my firs step be?

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter: You would start by installing the `DBI` and `DBD::SQLite` modules, if they're not already there. Then you just write the code: SQLite doesn't need a server. Do you know SQL? There is another possibility: do you need to keep the list of emails for each group ID? If you just need the count then the hash becomes feasible once more as it can be drastically reduced in size by making each hash value just a single scalar instead of an array of strings. Just change the `push` statement to `++$email_db{$id}`

Comment: @Borodin I am not the most familiar with SQLite, but I am reading up on it as we speak. I do need to keep the emails in the hash because I refer to them when sending emails, i.e. don't send an email to someone who is already in the hash.

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter: If you know `DBI` and SQL at all then that will suffice. You just need a simple two-column table with a (non-unique) `group_id` and a text `email`. You could make the `email` column unique so that you get an error if you try to add a duplicate address. The table should be a temporary one if you have no need to retain the data after the run. I'll throw some code together for you if you like

Comment: @Borodin I would absolutely love that :) I'm going to try as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses an SQLite database instead of a Perl hash to store the email information.

I can't add any code to send the email or to report the group counts as you haven't specified those parts.

As an alternative you may want to wait until all the input files have been read and inserted into the database before sending any emails.

It may be easier to debug this code if you remove the `TEMPORARY` attribute from the `emails` table so that it doesn't disappear when the program completes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
  'dbi:SQLite:dbname=email_db.sqlite', '', '',
  { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0 }
);

$dbh->do(<<END_SQL);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE emails (
  group_id INTEGER,
  email    TEXT,
  UNIQUE (group_id, email)
)
END_SQL

my $insert = $dbh->prepare(<<END_SQL);
INSERT INTO emails (group_id, email)
VALUES (?, ?)
END_SQL

$insert->{RaiseError} = 0;

while (<>) {
  next unless /-/;
  chomp;
  my ($group_id, $email) = split /-/;
  if ($insert->execute($group_id, $email)) {
    # Send email
  }
  else {
    my $errstr = $insert->errstr;
    die $errstr unless $errstr =~ /UNIQUE constraint failed/;
  }
}

my $sort = $dbh->prepare(<<END_SQL);
SELECT group_id, count(email)
FROM emails
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY count(email) DESC
END_SQL

$sort->execute;

while (my $row = $sort->fetchrow_arrayref) {
  printf "Group %d (%d emails)\n", @$row;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution and I adapted it for my purposes. The only thing I'm not sure how to do, is return a list to STDOUT from the DB that is ordered in this fashion: first -> last, Id w/most email addresses -> ID w/least email addresses. I'm guessing your would SORT your DB, and then grab a row at a time as you printed it.

Comment: Another thing that seems to be acting funky: if I have a file that contains: "1-test@test.com 2-test@test.com", it should add both of these. It should only ever not add an email that has the exact same key and ID.

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter: Okay I've made those changes. Take a look

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an SDBM hash? It's a hash linked to a file. This is a 'lite' solution which does not require a full database to be installed. Just plain Perl. Key size + data must be less than 1008 bytes.

```
use Fcntl; # Needed by SDBM_File
use SDBM_File;

# 'myemails' is the name of the file, and 2 files will be created: 
# myemails.pag and myemails.dir
tie(%h, 'myemails', 'filename', O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) 
or die "Couldn't tie SDBM file 'filename': $!; aborting";
# Now read and change the hash
$h{'bob@somewhere.com'} = 1; # This email now exists in hash.
print $h{'bob@somewhere.com'}."\n";
...
untie %h;
```

I've used a 500,000 line text file, but the script ran on our linux machine.

Plus this file will be there very time you run the script, so you will not be sending to dupe email addresses each day/week/month.

To clear out emails, move myemails.dir and myemails.pag to a backup file like: myemails2014-07.dir and myemails-2014-07.pag.

EDIT: Anyone know the limit to the number of keys in an SDBM or max size of an SDBM file? Will this work with 1 million email addresses? I have one SDBM file with 10,000 keys.

Comment: What if you had a few hundred email entries in the SDBM. Could you order the entire hash and print them to standard out without consuming all the memory? Additionally, my hash is somewhat weird. It has an ID as the key, and an array as the value. Would this structure work with that?

Comment: @ScottJamesWalter: Yes you could print them to stdout, but why would you do that? If you have hundreds, or thousands of emails, as your 1.5GB input file size suggested, wouldn't you want to output the emails to a text file? Then manipulate the text file from there? You can get all the keys of a hash by:   @a=sort(keys %h)); Now just print them out.

Comment: That was just part of the spec. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the module [Tie::File::AsHash](http://search.cpan.org/~cangell/Tie-File-AsHash-0.08/lib/Tie/File/AsHash.pm) or [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Tie-File-1.00/lib/Tie/File.pm).

I have not used either of them myself so do not have any experience to share.